# In Typescript, is it possible to map each element of an array to a different type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using a library (Constate) which contains types that I'd like to improve upon. It maps an array of functions to a different array of functions. Both arrays of functions share the same return types.

I.e. with objects, I can do:

```
const obj = {
  a: arg => 123,
  b: arg => 'str',
};

type T = { [k in keyof typeof obj]: () => ReturnType<typeof obj[k]> }
/*
T is {
  a: () => number;
  b: () => string;
}
*/
```

With arrays, this doesn't work:

```
const arr = [
  arg => 123,
  arg => 'str',
] as const;

type t2 = { [k in keyof typeof arr]: () => ReturnType<typeof arr[k]> }
/*
Type 'readonly [(_: any) => number, (_: any) => string][k]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type '((_: any) => number) | ((_: any) => string) | 2 | (() => string) | (() => string) | { (...items: ConcatArray<((_: any) => number) | ((_: any) => string)>[]): (((_: any) => number) | ((_: any) => string))[]; (...items: (((_: any) => number) | ... 1 more ... | ConcatArray<...>)[]): (((_: any) => number) | ((_: any) =>...' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type '2' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
*/
```

I'm assuming `Type '2'` in the error comes from `.length`.

Is there a way to get only the array indices and use it with an index signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript will [map arrays/tuples to arrays/tuples as of TypeScript 3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), but this only works when doing a *homomorphic* mapping of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ...}` where `T` is a *type parameter*, as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995#issuecomment-433056847) in the issue @basarat linked, [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  For now one way around this is to introduce indirection to turn your concrete type `typeof arr` into a type parameter:

```
type T2 = typeof arr extends infer A ? { [K in keyof A]: () => RT<A[K]> } : never;
```

Also note (as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#27351](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27351)) that the compiler refuses to understand that you're mapping over just the numeric indices, and so it will not believe that `A[K]` will always be a function... and so `ReturnType<A[K]>` will give an error.  My workaround here is to define my own `ReturnType` (called `RT`) which does not care if its argument is a function:

```
type RT<T> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never;
```

Given those, the type `T2` will evaluate to:

```
// type T2 = readonly [() => number, () => string]
```

which is presumably what you're trying to achieve here.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.9.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjAFIgcwC54wBPASlQD4YBGAJgGYAabPQkucqlWgcmgJ+bALrwIMUJCgBuTJihkADgFMYAJQAqAHi200WmKoAeUVWAAmk3ADp7hCFx40YASzAAzVcg0wA-JowJGCqAG4+8kpqMFoMqDDRqiCe8EjGZhbW7l4+MACCATAA3hgA0jkwANaqZCkFoiS4vLTaOvnoZaK0AL7BMKERCPIA9COJKupxCQiqcJbgADZkGM2uYACuALYARj4seC0wQh4EokA)

Comment: That's really cool! Could you explain what `typeof arr extends infer A` is doing? I read the docs on `infer` a few times. In this case, is `infer A` basically getting the subset of `A` that doesn't include stuff in `Array.prototype`?

Answer (score 3):

### short answer

To get the indices of a tuple, use:

```
type IdxOf<T> = { [idx in keyof T]: idx }[any]
```

instead of

```
keyof
```

### because...

```
const arr = [(_arg: any) => 123, (_arg: any) => 'str'] as const

// the issue is that `keyof typeof arr` is not just  "0" | "1"
type keyofArr = keyof typeof arr
// keyofArr is "0" | "1" | "length" | "toString" | ...

// IdxOf<T> fixes this:
type IdxOfArr = IdxOf<typeof arr>
// IdxOfArr is "0" | "1"

type t2 = { [k in IdxOf<typeof arr>]: () => ReturnType<typeof arr[k]> }
// t2 is { 0: () => number; 1: () => string; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues is that using mapped types over tuples lists over methods as well ([More details on this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995)).

## Quick Fix

List the keys manually if you must:

```
const obj = {
  a: () => 123,
  b: () => 'str',
};

type TObj = { [Key in keyof typeof obj]: () => ReturnType<typeof obj[Key]> }
/*
TOjb is {
  a: () => number;
  b: () => string;
}
*/

const arr = [
  () => 123,
  () => 'str',
] as const;

// type Keys = keyof typeof arr; // Instead of 
type Keys = '0' | '1'; // Use names 

type TArr = { [Key in Keys]: () => ReturnType<typeof arr[Key]> }
/*
  All good
*/
```